# Is ある in this sentence used to refer to animate objects (children)?

Tags: grammar, particles, syntax, abbreviations, casual

I was doing some searches and so know that it is not as simple as just ある = nonliving and いる = living, but the sentence still makes me confused because of "みんな的には…" and "良いとかある？"

> コレについてどう思う？良い子のみんな的にはもっと可愛いお人形の方が良いとかある？

context: He is trying to pressure kids to agree that there should be a redesign for a puppet.

When he says "みんな的には…ある？” is this like "Within something like you guys, is there...?" Could you also reword it something like "みんな的にはもっと可愛いお人形の方がいいとかいった子ある？" Otherwise, I'm having trouble understanding the structure of the sentence.

Comment: What do you think the subject of ある is?  That might be a good place to start and then work from there.  Keep in mind that the *subject* might have been provided in the context you've not quoted us here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This とかある is a very colloquial and informal construction. A polite version would be:

> もっと可愛いお人形の方が良い(など)ということはありますか？

And for this ある, the following definition may be related:

> #### [ある](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B/#jn-7643)
>
> 10 ある考え・気持ち・感覚などを持っている。「お願いが―・る」「言いたいことが―・る」「かすかな痛みが―・る」

In English, this type of ある roughly corresponds to *to have [a feeling, opinion, dream, question, pain, idea, etc.]*. In Japanese, we say 夢がある, 意見がある, 痛みがある, 考えがある, and so on, so the basic idea is the same here. The subject of this ある is an intangible "idea"; the speaker is asking whether the listeners **have** an idea/feeling indicated by the preceding noun clause. (とか can form a noun clause.)

You can also say "(～がいい)なんてこと(は)ある?".

---

**EDIT:** This `[person] + 的には` is another highly informal phrase that effectively means "in ～'s standpoint" or "for ～". For example, 私的には means "in my opinion" or "as far as I am concerned", but much more informally. You can also say ○○さん的には, あなた的には, etc. Don't use this in formal speech.